# MySQL INSERT INTO SELECT very slow

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I just created an empty table `document_test` which is a copy of the `document` table. I then add a new column host to `document_test` and copy everything else from `document`. The statement is like:

```
INSERT INTO document_test (id,col1,col2,col3,col4) SELECT * from document;
```

The `document` table contains about 5.5 million rows and I have disabled the keys in `document_test`, set `foreign_key_checks` to 0 and `unique_checks` to 0. This `INSERT` commands has been running for two days on a Linux server and has not been finished. The `SHOW PROCESSLIST` displays the state is "Sending Data". The `SELECT count(*) FROM document_test;` command returns 0. However, I do see from the `SHOW TABLE STATUS` command that the number of rows in `document_test` is non-zero. Interestingly, presumably, the row number should increase monotonously, but it is NOT.  The results of four consecutive queries are 3299583, 3325775, 3299730 and 3341818!

This is something that completely confuses me. Could someone help me on:
(1) is it inserting data?
(2) how to finish this insert in a timely manner? 
(2) is there any way to check the status of this `INSERT INTO SELECT` command? (what next after "sending Data")

Unfortunately, I did not turn on the slow-query-log and profiling before running this command.

Comment: How big are the actual data files involved?  Personally something on this scale I would have split into smaller batches i.e. 10-100k rows at a time, or I would have just used a backup file to create the clone.  It could be something as simple as your MySQL memory settings are too low to enable this type of import to run fast - it may have been advisable to increase the memory available to this query (no idea if you did this already)

Comment: I did adjust the memory allocation to MySQL, particularly, max_heap_table_size is set to 2048M, tmp_table_size is set to 2048M, query_cache_limit is set to 32M, query_cache_size is set to 16M. I tried to split the insert into small batches long time ago and I remembered that it did work, but I had to do it manually for 50 times. Is there any way to automate it?

Comment: I would have created a script in, for example, php or coldfusion, which would do the looping automatically however  you'll always have issues somewhere on this scale of database dump (probably) and the safest way is, as mentioned below, to mysqldump and LOAD DATA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try exporting the data using `mysqldump` and then imprt it via [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) ? That should be way more faster.

Comment: Good suggestion. I was considering doing that, but I want to use a different table name. Is there anyways to rename a table when dumping it out?

Comment: u can just dump the data and load it to whatever table You want :) If You look good at manual the `load data` has option: `INTO TABLE tbl_name` Anyway You will be surprised how fast `LOAD DATA` is, trust me.

Comment: Before I try this, I have one small concern: will LOAD DATA "know" which column it should feed data into? I am asking this because I created a new column after creating the document_test table.

Comment: When using mysqldump use `--extended-insert` end then just replace columns names, since it will be extended insert it won't be a hard task, never used it `this` way, so I don't know for sure if it will catch the new column's name.

Comment: Just tried this method and got my mission completed. Even if I do not set the --extended-insert, the dump and import are much faster. With 5 million rows, dumping cost about 10 min and importing using LOAD DATA INFILE cost about 30 min. You need to specify the column list when importing if the column in the  source file does not exactly match the columns in the table (must be created before importing). Another point is to use exactly the same delimeters (fields enclosed by, terminated by; lines terminated by) when you are dumping data out. Thanks for helping me out!